# Styling ipywidgets.Accordion panels, individually

Tags: python, ipywidgets

Is there a way to apply some styling (e.g. with CSS) on an `Accordion` widget? For example, I'd like to style a single pane in the Accordion to make the background color light yellow.

Note that setting a layout on the `Accordion` itself will style the container that holds the individual panes, while applying a layout to the `children` of the `Accordion` will style the contents of the panes, but not the panes themselves. How can I apply a style to the panes themselves? Ideally this would be at the individual level, but applying a style to all panes in an `Accordion` could be made to serve my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While ipywidgets' own styling system is still in active development, here is a somewhat hacky way to do it.

ipywidgets provides `add_class` method to allow you add a custom class to a widget, and you can use ipython's `HTML` method to add custom HTML to your notebook, so combine them together you can add any css to your widgets.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, HTML

#Create an accordion and add mystyle class on its first child widget
accordion = widgets.Accordion(children=[widgets.IntSlider(), widgets.Text()], titles=('Slider', 'Text')).add_class("parentstyle")
#Add a custom style tag to the notebook, you can use dev tool to inspect the class names
display(HTML("<style>.parentstyle > .p-Accordion-child > .p-Collapse-header{background-color:yellow}</style>"))
#Now the background of the title bars become yellow
display(accordion)
```

If you only want to add style to the open panel, you can use `display(HTML("<style>.parentstyle > .p-Collapse-open > .p-Collapse-header{background-color:yellow}</style>"))` instead of the css above, which will select the open panel.

Unfortunately, css `:has` pseudoclass is not widely available right now, so more fine grained control of the style isn't available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is exactly what I need. However I can only get it to work if I remove the `.parentstyle > ` CSS selector (tested in Safari & Chrome on Mac).

Comment: @corvus I forgot to add `add_class` method when creating accordion. Please check the updated code.